# Faster way to find Taylor series

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to figure out if there is a better way to teach the following Taylor series problem.  I can do the problem myself, but my solution doesn't seem very nice!

Let's say I want to find the first $n$ terms (small $n$ - say 3 or 4) in the Taylor series for

$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^2} 
$$

around $z_0 = 2$ (or more generally around any $z_0\neq 0$, to make it interesting!)  Obviously, two methods that come to mind are 1) computing the derivatives $f^{(n)}(z_0)$, which quickly turns into a bit of a mess, and 2) making a change of variables $w = z-z_0$, then computing the power series expansion for

$$
g(w) = \frac{1}{1+(w+z_0)^2}
$$ and trying to simplify it, which also turns into a bit of a mess.  Neither approach seems particularly rapid or elegant.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I assume you know $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+z}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n z^n $ already, no? Can you adjust it for your case?

Comment: @Tolaso that's what I meant by "making the substitution $w = z-2$".  It can be done, it's just messy.

Comment: Another trick involves noting that this function is the derivative of $\arctan(z)$, and then assuming that series expansions of common functions like $\arctan$ are known.

Comment: @asmeurer: But how do you find the series expansion of $\arctan z$?  Surely the easiest way is by integrating the series expansion for $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I usually find it by looking it up on Wikipedia.

Comment: @asmeurer: OK, how does wikipedia derive the series expansion of $\arctan z$?  (Hint: I looked already...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $g(w) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n w^n$.

Then
$(w^2+4w+5) \; g(w) = 1$ implies
$$\begin{align}
5 a_0 &= 1 \\
4 a_0 + 5 a_1 &= 0 \\
a_0 + 4 a_1 + 5 a_2 &= 0 \\
a_1 + 4 a_2 + 5 a_3 &= 0 \\
\text{etc.}
\end{align}$$

which you can then solve for the $a_n$'s in a stepwise fashion.

Comment: Very slick.  These equations come from differentiating both sides of $(w^2+4w+5)g(w) = 1$, correct?

Comment: @icurays1 I think you can get these equations by multiplying out the left side term-by-term; this seems simpler than my approach.

Comment: @icurays1, differentation is not involved.  The first equation results from looking at the coefficient of $1$ (the constant term) on both sides of the equation, the second from looking at the coefficient of $w$, the third from $w^2$, etc.

Comment: Got it, Robert Israel's answer (now deleted) goes through this in more detail.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to find the first few terms for $z_0=2$, using your idea of
letting $w=z-2$:

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{1+z^2}=\frac{1}{1+(w+2)^2}=\frac{1}{5+w^2+4w}=\frac{\frac{1}{5}}{1-(-\frac{w^2+4w}{5})}$

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{5}\left(1-\frac{w^2+4w}{5}+\frac{(w^2+4w)^2}{5^2}-\frac{(w^2+4w)^3}{5^3}+\cdots\right)$

$\displaystyle=\frac{1}{5}\left(1-\frac{w^2+4w}{5}+\frac{w^2(w+4)^2}{25}-\frac{w^3(w+4)^3}{125}+\cdots\right)$

$\displaystyle=\frac{1}{5}-\frac{4}{25}w+\frac{11}{125}w^2-\frac{24}{625}w^3+\cdots$

Comment: Oh hey, that's way better than what I was doing.  Still a bit of arithmetic to do, but probably about as good as it gets.

Answer (score 3):

For this particular problem, try a different substitution:  $x=z^2$.

Then 
$$
\frac1{1+x} = \sum (-1)^nx^n$$
so $$
\frac1{1+z^2} = \sum (-1)^nz^{2n}$$

The probelm of finding a closed form is not always easy.  If you can find a closed form for the coefficient of $z^k$ in 
$$
\frac{1}{(1-z)(1-z^2)(1-z^3)(1-z^4)\cdots}
$$
tell me about it so I can steal your result, publish it, and become famous.  (LOL - this will be a closed form for the partition number of $k$)

Comment: Is this around $z_0=2$, though?

Comment: Note that I'm trying to get the series around some $z_0\neq 0$.  You're right though, there probably isn't a nice solution!  (And if I did find that closed form, you can have it - I'll take 2nd author ;) )

Comment: That is the generating function for partitions. See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: The asymptotic formula for the coefficient of $z^n$ is
$p(n)
\sim 
\dfrac1{4n\sqrt{3}}
\exp(\pi\sqrt{\dfrac{2n}{3}})
$.